# Python scraping website shows unknown url type: view-source

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib

I am trying to do scraping in Python.

Then, I want to scrape a stock-info website. But I failed, I don't know why.

```
import urllib

# wallstreetcn info page
url_src = 'view-source:https://wallstreetcn.com/live/global?from=navbar'

url_content = urllib.request.urlopen(url_src)
```

It gives the error below:

```
URLError: urlopen error unknown url type: view-source
```

But when I used Chrome I can view the source code by right-click.

Comment: just remove the view-source:

Comment: What python version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `view-source:` from your `url_src`, in essence:

```
url_src = 'https://wallstreetcn.com/live/global?from=navbar'
```

I think `view-source:` is **Chrome specific** (so Chrome knows to show you source rather than the webpage).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html), you're not supposed to put `view-source`.